# apt-get update -y generates "invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel"

Tags: openvpn

Trying to run either an "**apt-get update -y**" and I keep getting some sort of error, any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

---

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS \n \l

root@ubuntu:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

root@ubuntu:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.10.105 #25426 SMP Wed Jul 8 03:19:33 CST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@ubuntu:~# apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa2048 2011-08-03 [SC] [expires: 2025-07-27]
      30EB F4E7 3CCE 63EE E124  DD27 8E6D A8B4 E158 C569
uid           [ unknown] Samuli Seppänen (OpenVPN Technologies, Inc) <samuli@openvpn.net>
sub   rsa2048 2011-08-03 [E] [expires: 2025-07-27]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
      F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list
deb http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable bionic main

root@ubuntu:/# openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.4.9 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Oct 30 2019
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2018 OpenVPN Inc <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=needless enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_maintainer_mode=no enable_management=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_silent_rules=no enable_small=no enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_sysroot=no


root@ubuntu:/# apt-get -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openvpn is already the newest version (2.4.9-bionic0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up openvpn (2.4.9-bionic0) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of cond-restart.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openvpn.postinst: 63: /var/lib/dpkg/info/openvpn.postinst: file: not found
dpkg: error processing package openvpn (--configure):
 installed openvpn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvpn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@ubuntu:~#
```

Comment: The output says `openvpn is already the newest version`. This is the answer to the question you asked about.  Is that really that question you meant to ask?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I guess I am still concerned that when I run "apt-get upgrade -y" I am still getting an error, if I have the most recent update, then why am I getting the errors: "invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel" and "invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of cond-restart."  I am running the command as root, and all other packages update just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be inventing a problem that does not exist.

Here are the current versions of `openvpn` for each release of Ubuntu:

```
$ rmadison openvpn
 openvpn | 2.2.1-8ubuntu1         | precise          | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 openvpn | 2.2.1-8ubuntu1.4       | precise-security | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 openvpn | 2.2.1-8ubuntu1.4       | precise-updates  | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 openvpn | 2.3.2-7ubuntu3         | trusty           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 openvpn | 2.3.2-7ubuntu3.2       | trusty-security  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 openvpn | 2.3.2-7ubuntu3.2       | trusty-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 openvpn | 2.3.10-1ubuntu2        | xenial           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 openvpn | 2.3.10-1ubuntu2.1      | xenial-security  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 openvpn | 2.3.10-1ubuntu2.2      | xenial-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 openvpn | 2.4.4-2ubuntu1         | bionic           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 openvpn | 2.4.4-2ubuntu1.3       | bionic-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 openvpn | 2.4.4-2ubuntu1.4       | bionic-proposed  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 openvpn | 2.4.7-1ubuntu2         | focal            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 openvpn | 2.4.7-1ubuntu2.20.04.1 | focal-proposed   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
 openvpn | 2.4.9-3ubuntu1         | groovy           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x
```

Note that older releases don't get newer versions. For newer software, use a newer release of Ubuntu.

- Older releases DO get security patches; older releases are safe to use.

Next, let's look upstream at Debian, and see [the recent OpenVPN uploads](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openvpn):

> [2020-08-16] Accepted openvpn 2.5~beta1-3 (source) into experimental

This means that a Debian volunteer has packaged OpenVPN 2.5, and uploaded it to Debian for testing. These newly-uploaded packages will be in a future release of Ubuntu...

...Probably not 20.10, though. [Debian Import Freeze for 20.10](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-schedule/15531) is August 27, 2020. Testing is unlikely to be completed so quickly.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't realize that openvpn 2.5 was currently still in beta release.   That being said, since I already have 2.4.9 installed, when I run "apt-get -y upgrade" or "apt-get -y --only-upgrade install openvpn", why do I get an error on the check for the openvpn package if I already have the most up to date version?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking... how to I remove it, and add the correct source, and switch to the correct version of openvpn?

Comment: It says below this box "Comments are used to ask for clarification"... I thought this was a help forum, forget it, sorry I asked... I don't know how 2.4.9 got installed, I shared the output of my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list file, the last time it updated I just ran three commands: "apt-get update -y", "apt-get upgrade -y" and "apt-get dist-upgrade -y"